# CSS Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, css-loader

Error: Module build failed: ValidationError: Invalid options object. CSS Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.

- options has an unknown property 'localIdentName'. These properties are valid:
  object { url?, import?, modules?, icss?, sourceMap?, importLoaders?, esModule? }

below is the package.json file of my create-react-app
please help me find the error.

```
         {
          "name": "burger-project",
          "version": "0.1.0",
          "private": true,
          "dependencies": {
          "autoprefixer": "7.1.6",
          "axios": "^0.19.2",
    
     "babel-core": "6.26.0",
           "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
                "babel-jest": "^26.3.0",
                "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
                "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.2",
                "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
                "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
                "chalk": "1.1.3",
                "dotenv": "4.0.0",
                "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
                "eslint": "4.10.0",
                "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.1.0",
                "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
                "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.39.1",
                "eslint-plugin-import": "2.8.0",
                "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
                "eslint-plugin-react": "7.4.0",
                "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
                "file-loader": "1.1.5",
                "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
                "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
                "jest": "^26.4.2",
                "object-assign": "4.1.1",
                "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
                "postcss-loader": "2.0.8",
                "promise": "8.0.1",
                "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
                "raf": "3.4.0",
                "react": "^16.13.1",
                "react-dev-utils": "^5.0.2",
                "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
                "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
                "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
                "redux": "^4.0.5",
                "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
                "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
                "resolve": "1.6.0",
                "style-loader": "0.19.0",
                "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
                "url-loader": "0.6.2",
                "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1",
                "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.3.2",
                "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
              },
              "scripts": {
                "start": "node scripts/start.js",
                "build": "node scripts/build.js",
                "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
              },
              "jest": {
                "collectCoverageFrom": [
                  "src/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}"
                ],
                "setupFiles": [
                  "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
                ],
                "testMatch": [
                  "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}",
                  "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,mjs}"
                ],
                "testEnvironment": "node",
                "testURL": "http://localhost",
                "transform": {
                  "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
                  "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
                  "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
                },
                "transformIgnorePatterns": [
                  "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$"
                ],
                "moduleNameMapper": {
                  "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
                },
                "moduleFileExtensions": [
                  "web.js",
                  "js",
                  "json",
                  "web.jsx",
                  "jsx",
                  "node",
                  "mjs"
                ]
              },
              "babel": {
                "presets": [
                  "react-app"
                ]
              },
              "eslintConfig": {
                "extends": "react-app"
              },
              "devDependencies": {
                "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^1.0.2",
                "css-loader": "^3.1.0",
                "webpack": "^3.0.0"
              }
            }
```